# PHP installation warning: [function.require-once]: failed to open stream

Tags: php, file-io, stream, xampp, require-once

Im having problems trying to install locally a script of a groupon clone.
Im using XAMPP running in windows7

```
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 
OpenSSL/0.9.8o 
PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625
```

This is what I get trying to run index.php:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 80

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config.php on line 166

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Config\Container.php on line 111


Warning: require_once(DOCUMENT_ROOT/system/plugins/common.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Eclipse\xxxx\system\includes\library.inc.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'DOCUMENT_ROOT/system/plugins/common.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Eclipse\xxxx\system\includes\library.inc.php on line 17
```

The php file start like this:

```
session_start();
require_once ('config.php');        // this is the one that defines DOCUMENT_ROOT
require_once ('functions.php');
require_once ('functions_theme.php');
require_once ('fns.php');
```

Here is line 17:

```
    require_once (DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/system/plugins/common.php');
```

DOCUMENT_ROOT is defined like this in config.php file that is loaded before:

```
define("DOCUMENT_ROOT",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Hope someone can help.

And YES, the file is in that directory (already checked that :P).

Comment: That other PHP file obviously isn't being included, or that line isn't being run.

Comment: Are you sure that the file containing the `define` statement is really loaded before you are trying to include your file? The `Warning: require_once(DOCUMENT_ROOT/system/plugins/common.php)` parts seems to tell that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` haven't been defined yet.

Comment: The file that defines the constant is loaded before calling that other file.

Comment: 1. Are your code examples copied from your code, or manually typed into the question? 2. Can you show a more complete script (for example, the 16 lines above the error)? 3. Is this the only warning? 4. Also, what happens when you `var_dump(DOCUMENT_ROOT);` immediately after the you define it - do you get any output?

Comment: I've updated the question with the things you asked.
Hope u can help me

Comment: can't see why you'd be having this problem from what you've provided - what do you get when you var_dump the DOCUMENT_ROOT immediately after defining it, and also immediately after requiring the config.php

Comment: when I var_dump after defining it I get: string(13). Then when I var_dump after requiring config.php I get "DOCUMENT_ROOT"

Comment: I solved it !
I changed the `include_path =` in php.ini

It was set to: `include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"` 

and I changed it to: `include_path = ".;C:\Users\dan\Documents\Eclipse\projectName"`

and It worked like a charm !

Someone know how can I add more than one path? cause I dont want to break sth changing that path. Thank youu !

Comment: use a `;` to separate paths, e.g. include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\Users\dan\Documents\Eclipse\projectName"`. but isn't this a work around, or was it actually not including the config.php file?

Answer (score 1):

The `DOCUMENT_ROOT` constant is not being resolved correctly (I think the file you are including which defines it is not being included correctly) and PHP is falling back to using the string `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

Comment: Yes, I dont know why cause is loaded before calling the other file that Im getting the warning.